# Is it a norm or a seminorm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ Hilbert space and $B \in L(X)$ positive, self adjoint operator. Then is this a norm or seminorm?
$$|x|_B=(\langle Bx,x\rangle)^{1/2}$$

In  [Li, Xungjing, and Jiongmin Yong. Optimal control theory for infinite dimensional systems.1995] p.232 they claim it's a seminorm.

But since $B$ is positive I can define $B^{1/2}$ which is a positive self adjoint operator and then
$$|x|_B=(\langle Bx,x\rangle )^{1/2}=(\langle B^{1/2}x,B^{1/2}x\rangle )^{1/2}=|B^{1/2}x|$$
which is zero only for $x=0$ by the positivity of $B^{1/2}$.

What am I missing?

The thing that come to mind is that of course $\langle Bx,x\rangle =0$ when $Bx$ is orthogonal to $x$ but this seems not to be the case thanks to the previous equality.

Comment: Positive operators need not be injective. $B=0$ is also a positive operator.

Comment: It depends if a positive operator is allowed to have a kernel. My definition allows it! And if I want a positive operator not to have a kernel, I would say a "positive definite operator", I guess.

Comment: Yes, it's rather a terminology question, 'positive operator' here means *positive semidefinite*.

Comment: Yeah thanks I was pretty sure that it didnt admit a kernel. But checking better it does

Comment: yes right @Berci with positive I immidiately meant positive semidefinite, but it's semidefinite what it was meant

Comment: ATTENTION: I was wrong, $B$ has a null kernel: it can be seen for example at p.249 of [LY95] where $B^{-1}$ is defined on the range of $B$

Comment: I added in the question: "The thing that come to mind is that of course $<Bx,x>=0$ when $Bx$ is orthogonal to $x$ but this seems not to be the case thanks to the previous equality"

Comment: Note that $X$ is not complete under $|x|_B$, see p.249 [LY95]. Maybe they mean that it is not a proper norm since $X$ under $|x|_B$ is not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained by @Plop and @Berci, it depends on whether $B$ is *strictly positive definite* or only *positive semidefinite*.

For a *positive semidefinite* $B$, you may have some $v \in X$, $ v \neq 0 $ with $Bv = 0$. Then also $ |x|_B = 0 $ and $ |\cdot |_B $ this is only a seminorm, not a norm.

For a *strictly positive definite* $ B $, also $ B^{1/2} $ is strictly positive definite (by spectral calculus), so $ x \neq 0 $ implies $ |B^{1/2}x| > 0 $ and
$$ |x|_B = |B^{1/2}x| > 0, $$

so you indeed have a norm.